# llamar datos javascript, react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gráficas, amazon

buen dia, soy nuevo en javascript y en react, en mi trabajo me han pedido hacer graficas, yo ocupo rechart y me mandaron un json de amazon:

[image: codigo]

eso lo tengo que mandar a llamar y ponerlo en la grafica, intente hacerlo como las demas graficas que tenia

```
componentDidMount() {
this.llamarDatas()
this.vehiculoPorColores()
}
```

y

```
vehiculoPorColores = () => {
const _this = this
fetch("/live/graph/color")
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(datos => {
    _this.setState(
      {
        vehiculosC: datos.map((e, i) => {
          let k = Object.keys(e)[0]
          let obj = e[k]
          return { name: k, vehicles: obj.count }
        })
      },
      () => setTimeout(this.vehiculoPorColores, 1000)
    )
  })
  }
```

pero me da este error

[image: error]

esta seria la grafica aunque en la grafica si tengo bien como mandarlos a llamar

```
{this.state.vehiculosC && (
                  <ResponsiveContainer>
                    <BarChart
                      data={this.state.vehiculosC}
                      margin={{
                        top: 0,
                        right: 30,
                        left: 0,
                        bottom: 20
                      }}>
                      <CartesianGrid strokeDasharray="3 3" />
                      <XAxis tickMargin={20} dataKey="name" />
                      <YAxis tickMargin={20} />
                      <Tooltip />
                      <Bar dataKey="colores" fill="#F29120" />
                    </BarChart>
                  </ResponsiveContainer>
                )}
```

necesito ayuda, casi no se javascript o mejor dicho no se

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La razón por la que no puedes usar el map en **datos**, es porque asumo no estás recibiendo un objeto tipo `Array`, en la cual esta incluida la función `map`

Te recomiendo que hagas lo siguiente, antes de usar el `setState` verifica que estas obteniendo en **datos** ya sea haciendo un **console.log()** o usando alguna herramienta cómo **Postman**

Al tratarse de un `Object` la manera de obtener los valores sería la siguiente

```
vehiculoPorColores = () => {
  const _this = this
  fetch("/live/graph/color")
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(datos => {
      const vehicleKey = Object.keys(datos);
      _this.setState(
        {
          vehiculosC: vehicleKey.map((e, i) => ({ name: vehicleKey[i], datos[e] })
        },
       () => {
         setTimeout(this.vehiculoPorColores, 1000)
       }
    )
  })
}
```

Comment: gracias por la ayuda amigo, yo tengo insomnia y cuandohago el send me tira esto   {
    "lavender": 3,
    "white": 13,
    "dimgrey": 4,
    "seagreen": 2,
    "lightslategrey": 6,
    "slategrey": 7,
    "indianred": 2,
    "snow": 1,
    "darkslategrey": 1,
    "khaki": 1,
    "gainsboro": 3,
    "palevioletred": 1,
    "darkgrey": 1,
    "grey": 1,
    "black": 1
}

Comment: Este es un `Object`, no tiene función map.. actualizaré la respuesta para poner un código que te puede servir

Comment: muchas gracias Benjamin